# xampp MySQL won't start anymore

Tags: mysql, xampp

I am unable to start the mysql service from xampp control panel. It worked yesterday but stopped working as of sudden today. This is the mysql error log file (mysql_error.log):

```
    InnoDB: using atomic writes.
2021-02-01 14:32:27 0 [Note] InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use Windows interlocked functions
2021-02-01 14:32:27 0 [Note] InnoDB: Uses event mutexes
2021-02-01 14:32:27 0 [Note] InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.11
2021-02-01 14:32:27 0 [Note] InnoDB: Number of pools: 1
2021-02-01 14:32:27 0 [Note] InnoDB: Using SSE2 crc32 instructions
2021-02-01 14:32:27 0 [Note] InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, total size = 16M, instances = 1, chunk size = 16M
2021-02-01 14:32:27 0 [Note] InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
2021-02-01 14:32:27 0 [Note] InnoDB: 128 out of 128 rollback segments are active.
2021-02-01 14:32:27 0 [Note] InnoDB: Creating shared tablespace for temporary tables
2021-02-01 14:32:27 0 [Note] InnoDB: Setting file 'C:\xampp\mysql\data\ibtmp1' size to 12 MB. Physically writing the file full; Please wait ...
2021-02-01 14:32:27 0 [Note] InnoDB: File 'C:\xampp\mysql\data\ibtmp1' size is now 12 MB.
2021-02-01 14:32:27 0 [Note] InnoDB: Waiting for purge to start
2021-02-01 14:32:27 0 [Note] InnoDB: 10.4.11 started; log sequence number 59458941; transaction id 147015
2021-02-01 14:32:27 0 [Note] InnoDB: Loading buffer pool(s) from C:\xampp\mysql\data\ib_buffer_pool
2021-02-01 14:32:27 0 [Note] Plugin 'FEEDBACK' is disabled.
2021-02-01 14:32:27 0 [Note] Server socket created on IP: '::'.
```

And there is no result from the command netstat -ano|find "3306" in windows 10, so no other application is using the port. I also tried changing the port, but did not work either.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Check the Windows Event Log for messages from mariaDB

Comment: There is no error in the log extract.